# Poems about parents love and care for children

Tags: poetry

I'm looking for poems about parents' love, concern, and caring of their children.

I'm aware of 孟郊《游子吟》:

> “慈母手中线,游子身上衣。临行密密缝,意恐迟迟归。谁言寸草心,报得三春晖?”

But that's heavy on the "repayment" aspect.

I'm looking for something that emphasizes the amount of effort, time, energy parents put into taking care of their children.

Something well known is preferable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question about Chinese "literature", rather than about Chinese language per se.

Comment: My VTC is based on the fact that my experience has been on language sites that literature questions, unless relevant to the language itself (e.g. "what's with this wording in the Bible"), are not really on topic.

Comment: @Maroon We don't have a `Chinese Literature` site, so...

Comment: @songyuanyao there was a similar discussion on the English site. There's no general literature site either, but questions specifically about literature in English are off-topic there.

Comment: @Maroon Just want to say that I understand why you'd want to vote off-topic on this question, but isn't it a pity to discourage people from asking question that would actually helps with understanding the Chinese Language?  On the other hand, if it's suspected to be some sort of 'homework' question, i'll agree with you on closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

《**送母回乡**》
    ——**李商隐**
停车茫茫顾，困我成楚囚。
感伤从中起，悲泪哽在喉。
慈母方病重，欲将名医投。
车接今在急，天竟情不留！
母爱无所报，人生更何求！

Meaning:

***When I stopped the carriage and looking around blankly,
I felt like a prisoner because of the sadness I've gone through.
My grief tear is like fishbone stuck in my throat.
Now my mother is sick(lethally sick),
so I'm taking her to visit the doctor.
But on the way,
the God(sky) took my mother's life mercilessly.
I can't pay back for my mother's love,
what else can I look forward to?***

Answer (score 0):

《诗经·邶风·凯风》

> 凯风自南，吹彼棘心。
>   棘心夭夭，母氏劬劳。 
>   凯风自南，吹彼棘薪。
>   母氏圣善，我无令人。 
>   爰有寒泉？在浚之下。
>   有子七人，母氏劳苦。 
>   睍睆黄鸟，载好其音。
>   有子七人，莫慰母心。